# Why query do not use keys corectly?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, explain

I have this complicated query:

```
SELECT * FROM `s` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `iu` ON iu.user_id = s.s_iu_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `uu` ON uu.user_id = s.uu_id 
LEFT JOIN `sic` ON sic.s_id = s.s_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `ppu` ON ppu.user_id = sic.pure_price_user_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `spu` ON spu.user_id = sic.spu_id 
LEFT JOIN `us` ON f_user_id = 8714 AND users.f_s_id = s.s_id 
LEFT JOIN `c` ON c.c_id = sic.c_id 
LEFT JOIN `countries` ON countries.country_id = s.country_id 
LEFT JOIN `countries` AS `countries2` ON countries2.country_id = countries.parent_id 
LEFT JOIN `continents` ON continents.continent_id = countries.continent_id 
LEFT JOIN `countryperiods` ON countryperiods.countryPeriod_id = s.countryPeriod_id 
LEFT JOIN `currencies` ON currencies.currency_id = countryperiods.currency_id 
LEFT JOIN `serrations` AS `s1` ON s.serration_width_id = s1.id 
LEFT JOIN `serrations` AS `s2` ON s.serration_height_id = s2.id 
LEFT JOIN `colors` ON colors.color_id = s.color_id 
LEFT JOIN `colors` AS `c2` ON c2.color_id = s.background_id 
LEFT JOIN `colors` AS `c3` ON c3.color_id = s.color2_id 
WHERE (s.fsis_id = '141518') AND (sic.c_id = '1') AND 
((s.s_enabled = 1) OR (s.s_iu_id = '8714')) AND 
(s.s_exists = 1) 
ORDER BY `c_number` ASC, `cn_prepend` ASC, `cn_append` ASC 
LIMIT 10000
```

**Explain:**

```
id  s_type  table          type       possible_keys            key            key_len   ref                            rows    Extra 
1   SIMPLE  sic            range      catNum,catalog_s_id      catalog_s_id   10        NULL                           132480  Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  ppu            eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4         data.sic.pure_price_user_id    1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  spu            eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4         data.sic.stamped_price_user_id 1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  s              eq_ref     PRIMARY,s_insertUser_id  PRIMARY        4         data.sic.s_id                  1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  us             ref|filter us,f_s_id,f_user_id      f_s_id|f_user_id  5|5    data.sic.s_id                  1 (0%)  Using where; Using rowid filter
1   SIMPLE  c              ALL        PRIMARY                  NULL           NULL  NULL                               2       Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
1   SIMPLE  countries      ALL        PRIMARY                  NULL           NULL     NULL                            494     Using where; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join)
1   SIMPLE  countries2     eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4        data.countries.parent_id        1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  continents     eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4        data.countries.continent_id     1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  countryperiods eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4        data.s.countryPeriod_id         1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  iu             eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4        data.s.s_insertUser_id          1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  uu             eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4        data.s.uploadUser_id            1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  currencies     ALL        PRIMARY                  NULL           NULL     NULL                            281     Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
1   SIMPLE  s1             eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4        data.s.serration_width_id       1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  s2             eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4        data.s.serration_height_id      1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  colors         eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4        data.s.color_id                 1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  c2             eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4        data.s.background_id            1       Using where
1   SIMPLE  c3             eq_ref     PRIMARY                  PRIMARY        4        data.s.color2_id                1       Using where
```

Why tables c, countries and currencies do not use primary index when is the same join as with others? Ca I optmize it? Query durate 1.3883s.

[image]

Comment: c and currencies tables seem very small, so it is probably impractical to use an index unless it is a covering one. Countries table is the interesting one as once it uses PK, the other time it does not. No clear answer there why not. You could try to use force index hint to make mysql use the PKs and compare the speed.

Comment: However, to me the sic table seems to be the bottle neck, not the three you mentioned. Using temporary, using filesort in the explain does not bode well for speed on a large table.

Comment: Probably because the table is so small that it's less I/O time to read the whole table than it is to read the index pages in and then read the data page in, especially considering reading contiguous disk pages is much faster than having to change the disk sector while reading.

Comment: @Shadow the forced index did not speed up the query. The only interesting thing is that when I forced the index on countries and currencies, it stopped being used for continents and countrperiods. How can I avoid using temporary and filesort?

Comment: @Bohemian you're right. So that won't be the main brake. Can I optimize the query at all to take a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Are `sic.c_id` and `s.s_iu_id` integer types or a text datatypes? Do you have indexes defined on all the id columns?

Comment: yes all IDs are of type INT. Apostrophes are added by the framework, I retyped them back to INT. Indexes on IDs are defined in a composite index (see edit question). It worked faster than individually.

Answer (score 0):

Move `sic.c_id = 1` from the `where` clause to the `join` condition; putting it in the `where` clause forces the join to `sic` to be an `INNER` join.

Also change all conditions on ids to be compared to integers, not strings, eg `s.fsis_id = 141518` not `s.fsis_id = '141518'`.

Ensure there are indexes on all "id" columns (columns you're looking up on, which all seem to end with "id").

```
SELECT *
FROM `s` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `iu` ON iu.user_id = s.s_iu_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `uu` ON uu.user_id = s.uu_id 
LEFT JOIN `sic` ON sic.s_id = s.s_id AND sic.c_id = 1
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `ppu` ON ppu.user_id = sic.pure_price_user_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `spu` ON spu.user_id = sic.spu_id 
LEFT JOIN `us` ON f_user_id = 8714 AND users.f_s_id = s.s_id 
LEFT JOIN `c` ON c.c_id = sic.c_id 
LEFT JOIN `countries` ON countries.country_id = s.country_id 
LEFT JOIN `countries` AS `countries2` ON countries2.country_id = countries.parent_id 
LEFT JOIN `continents` ON continents.continent_id = countries.continent_id 
LEFT JOIN `countryperiods` ON countryperiods.countryPeriod_id = s.countryPeriod_id 
LEFT JOIN `currencies` ON currencies.currency_id = countryperiods.currency_id 
LEFT JOIN `serrations` AS `s1` ON s.serration_width_id = s1.id 
LEFT JOIN `serrations` AS `s2` ON s.serration_height_id = s2.id 
LEFT JOIN `colors` ON colors.color_id = s.color_id 
LEFT JOIN `colors` AS `c2` ON c2.color_id = s.background_id 
LEFT JOIN `colors` AS `c3` ON c3.color_id = s.color2_id 
WHERE s.fsis_id = 141518
AND (s.s_enabled = 1 OR s.s_iu_id = 8714)
AND s.s_exists = 1
ORDER BY `c_number`, `cn_prepend`, `cn_append` 
LIMIT 10000
```

(unnecessary brackets removed for clarity)

Comment: '141518' it 141518 didn't help much, but moving sic.c_id = 1 to join did. The query is executed in 0.2s. It returns a record anyway, even if it doesn't find anything in the table, as long as there are NULL values. I would need it to filter out those records, which only where does. Only with join or right join I achieved the same result, but the execution time was still around 1s. Is it possible to get rid of inner join in where?

Comment: What do you mean "get rid of inner join in where"? With `sic.c_id = 1` in the join, this query has no inner join. Please explain more.